# Como obter registros não duplicados com mongoDB e Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Como faço para que o mongoDB me retorne uma lista de documentos não duplicados.

No meu caso o mongoDB retorna uma lista de ingredientes de todas as receitas cadastradas, mas eu quero esses registros sem duplicação por que as receitas podem repetir os mesmos ingredientes. Como posso resolver este problema?

```
List<Datasheet> datasheets = 
            getDatastore().find(Datasheet.class).retrievedFields(true, "ingredients").asList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando a biblioteca GSON da Google. Apenas adicionei o jar da lib para utilizar dos métodos.

Segue o código:

```
public List<Ingredient> listIngredients() throws Exception {

    // Para usar o distinct tivemos que utilizar o getCollection
    List ingredientsDB = getDatastore().getCollection(Datasheet.class).distinct("ingredients");
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    // Como a lista vinda do banco é DBObject tivemos que usar a lib Gson para atribuir o JSON a lista de ingredientes
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    for (int i = 0; i < ingredientsDB.size(); i++) {
        ingredients.add(gson.fromJson(ingredientsDB.get(i).toString(), Ingredient.class));
    }

    return ingredients;
}//listIngredients
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira saber apenas os valores distintos para um determinado campo em um conjunto de documentos em uma collection, você pode utilizar o distinct. db.collection.distinct(field, query).

Entretanto se você deseja retornar um conjunto de 'documentos' distintos por um determinado campo, neste caso você deverá utilizar o MapReduce, ou o aggregate, vai depender da sua necessidade.

O MongoDB é um banco 'burro', ele faz pouca logica por você, no caso de buscar documentos distintos por um campo, é necessário alguma logica para excluir os documentos que não devem ser retornados e o MongoDB não oferece uma logica desta de forma nativa, mais oferece um meio pelo qual você pode implementar que é utilizando o db.collection.mapReduce. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/